# access key parameter in nested block

Tags: ruby, proc

I'm facing difficulties accessing a parameter in a block created from a `Proc` that... See for yourselves:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_transform' for #<API::Portal:0x0000556037915cc0>>
["api.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in access'", ...]
```

```
module API
  def self.access(s, delete: false, read_transform: proc(&:itself))
    proc {
      path = "/#{s}"
      define_method(s) {
        read_transform(query(:GET, path).body) # this is line 23
      }

      define_method("#{s}=") { |v|
        query(API::_method(v, delete), path).body
      }
    }
  end
end
```

The block was used to extend a class like this: `class_eval &API::access(:name)`
The call triggering the exception is `api.name`.

`s` appears to work inside the block to build `path`. Why isn't `read_transform` accessible in the inner blocks?
Am I doing scopes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake i made was 'not interpreting the error correctly':
`` undefined method `read_transform' ``

`read_transform` is defined - just not as a method but as a proc.

Changing the line in question from

```
read_transform(query(:GET, path).body)
```

to

```
read_transform.call(query(:GET, path).body)
```

fixes the error and results in the expected behaviour.